# tclsh script within a sh script permissions

Tags: ubuntu, bash, permissions, script, tcl

I am having an issue with calling a tclsh script from within a sh script on Ubuntu.

I can call the tclsh script form the terminal successfully, yet as soon as I try and automate its calling from within the sh script it fails. I believe it to be a permissions error but have no idea how to correct it.

My process is as follows, note that I am running everything as root and have tried giving every script executable permissions also I am trying to reduce the complexity of the problem:

```
./shellscript.sh
```

shellscript.sh:

```
#!/bin.bash    
#do stuff
delete.tcl
```

delete.tcl:

```
#!/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6/bin/tclsh

file delete test.txt
```

test.txt is silently not deleted.

In a more complicated scenario I am unable to connect to a port because of what I presume to be similar permissions issues.

Any idea how I could approach this differently, or fix my permissions issue?

Comment: 1. does delete.tcl have execute permissions? 2. is it located in a diectory in your $PATH?

Comment: Are you sure your file delete case isn't a path or working directory problem?

Comment: good point: @tom where is test.txt? is it in the same dir as ./shellscript.sh?

Comment: I know the directory not to be an issue, and while I didn't note it, there is a pushd to the correct directory,  also this is a simplification of a different problem, which due to being a connection problem does not have directory issues.

1. delete.tcl has execute permissions. 2. delete.tcl is not in $PATH (though why should it be)